# Empty Div Causing Very Strange Behavior

Tags: xslt, html

Got something like this

```
<div class="something">

<div></div>

<p>
Some text here
</p>

</div>
```

This is all called in a template in XSL.

For some reason I am getting when it's rendered that the empty div is never closed. The `<p>` and its contents are inside this div. This continues on and on for each time this template is called. :( If I only take out the empty div, all the "something" divs are separate entities and not inside each other.

How could this be happening?!

Comment: This can be an XSLT issue. Do you have code sample?

Comment: Simple.  Your XSLT doesn't do what you think it's doing.  @Flack's right:  Let's see some code.

Comment: Hey bobber, I adjusted the tags to push the topic to more XSLT people - CSS isn't part of the problem. Hope that's cool.

Comment: It's hard helping you just seeing the result HTML of some mentioned XSLT code :)

Comment: "For some reason I am getting when it's rendered that the empty div is never closed". The empty div is closed in the HTML you show above. You mean it's not closed in this way `<div/>`?

Comment: Might be important: What <xsl:output method are you using? ( xml or html ) ?

Comment: Agree with @deathy - I've seen cases where the div is closed as <div/> when using xml output method.

Comment: -1 for the poor consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting an

```
&nbsp;
```

inside the empty div.