# Empty div causing alignment issues in FF

Tags: css, firefox, html, alignment

I am facing a similar issue as following post

[Empty Div Causing Very Strange Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476063/empty-div-causing-very-strange-behavior)

Answer dint help me much. &nbsp fixes alignment issue, but my html code is generated by spring, so I have to find a way to fix it via CSS. I have uploaded sample code at http://jsfiddle.net/sZ77p/1/

If you add an &nbsp or any text in empty lines under HTML code and run, alignment comes perfectly. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `div {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving your divs and explicit height? Per your example:

```
div {
  line-height: normal;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  height: 16px;
}
```